# How to use onClickOutside (vueuse) on two dom elements?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, ref, vueuse

The `onClickOutside` function from `vueuse` package can be used to trigger when a click event happens outside the `ref`:

```
const imageRef = ref(null)

onClickOutside(imageRef, (event) => {
    state.active = false
})
```

dom element:

```
<img ... ref="imageRef"/>
```

but is there a way to use it on two dom elements? What I want is to trigger the function, when the user clicks outside of two elements. I've tried adding the same `ref` on two dom elements but the ref just gets overwritten by the second one. Said dom elements are **NOT** rendered in a `v-for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle this still via `vueuse`, there is an option: [`ignore`](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/onClickOutside/index.ts#L12)

```
<template>
    <img ... ref="imageRef"/>
    <p ... ref="pRef"/>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { onClickOutside } from '@vueuse/core'

const imageRef = ref(null), pRef = ref(null), state = ref({active: false});

const doSomething = () => {state.value.active = true};

onClickOutside(imageRef, doSomething, {ignore: [pRef]});
onClickOutside(pRef, doSomething, {ignore: [imageRef]});
</script>
```